# Override for <td> in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Client.css hosted on another server.

```
td { background: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; }
```

Can I override this for IE7?

I’m trying to remove the background property on this element.  The background forces everything in IE7 to be invisible on `<tr>` and `<td>` elements, as I don't think it allows this in IE7.

Comment: `td { *background: none !important; }`

Comment: I'm also trying do this without having to edit the clients linked stylesheet.  I know the conditional stylesheet stuff but it doesn't help when the client changes their files fairly often.

Comment: So you want a CSS solution that doesn't alter their files? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my stylesheet I can override the specific client style be defining the particular class and then the td which will override the clients style.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.com/client.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css"/>
```

inside my linked stylesheet

```
.class > td { background: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For IE7 only

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/client.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For IE 7 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/client.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use the `!important` rule, and conditional stylesheets:

In your `<head>`, add:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

And then inside `ie7.css`, simply create the following CSS rule:

```
td { background: #fff !important; }
```